# One Angular controller but each method inside a separate file

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js

I want to have one Angular controller but each method inside a separate file and $scope shares in all files. in fact,  its a single controller but decomposed into several files.

i do something like this but it doesnt work:

**file1.js**

```
var app = angular.module("main");
app.controller("mainCtrl", function ($scope) {
    $scope.method1 = function (content) {

    };
});
```

**file2.js**

```
var app = angular.module("main");
app.controller("mainCtrl", function ($scope) {
    $scope.method2 = function (content) {

    };
});
```

**file3.js**

```
var app = angular.module("main");
app.controller("mainCtrl", function ($scope) {
    $scope.method3 = function (content) {

    };
});
```

Comment: you can not decompose single controller in many file. but you can use angular service and use them in  many controller

Comment: I think you missed the empty array to declare your module, you should declare your module like this: "var app = angular.module("main", []);", like it's said in the doc :https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/module,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are doing now, is actually overwriting everything again. For example, you specify the `app` 3 times, so you actually create 3 apps (which you always overwrite again). You can only create a controller once, and as far as I know, you can't update a controller later on. So you'll have to specify every method you want in the controller at once.

Looks like you want to use different [services](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/services). If you create a service for each method, you can then specify all of these services in your controller. You can then access the methods using these services.

You can then group these services together like this:

```
app.controller("mainCtrl", ["$scope", "name-of-service1", "name-of-service2",
    function($scope, service1, service2){
        $scope.service1Method = service1.method;
        $scope.service2Method = service2.method;
    }
]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Methods inside controller can not be shared. Angularjs Services are used to share data between two or more objects.

To complete this task create a service and add dependency in controller, so you can use service single method any where in any controller

**angular Service**

```
module.service('MyService', function() {
this.method1 = function() {
        //..
    }

this.method2 = function() {
        //..
    }

});
```

**using service in controller**

```
module.controller('myController',function(MyService){
    //You can use service method like service-name.method-name
    MyService.method2()
})
```